# How to disable require my password under CMD in unity?

Tags: unity, password

We want to make a image with no entering passward when awaking from suspend in ubuntu unity. How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No more unity, this is Gnome.

Answer (score 0):

If the following is what you want

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend 'false'
```

Then simply follow the guide about changing gconf values in custom live iso:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization#Change_gconf_values_.28fonts.2C_panels_etc..29

*Once chrooted, run this

`gconftool-2 --direct --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults --type string --set yourkey "yourvalue"`*